# Deploy API to Amazon API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

In the *Amazon API Gateway* I have created a simple API containing a single resource called **demo** and one **POST** method corresponding to it:

[image]

Now, I want my endpoint to accept *POST* request of **any** *Content-Type*, so not necessarily *application/json*, but also *plain/text*. I then want to take the *body* of the request and wrap it in a *JSON* object and send it to an *Amazon Lambda function* (*Lambda* functions can only accept *JSON* object as parameter).

For this purpose I have edited the *Integration Request* corresponding to my method to use a custom template mapping:

[image]

I have used the reference from the Amazon documentation which can be found here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html

My *Lambda function* looks like this:

```
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    context.succeed(event);
};
```

When testing, I get the expected output regardless of what I send:

[image]

However, when I deploy, the transformation just doesn't work anymore, it expects *JSON*

- Sending anything yelds this:

[image]

- Sending JSON yields this:

[image]

Is there any part of this process executed wrong? Am I missing something when deploying? To me, it looks like a very annoying Amazon bug, can anyone confirm that?

Comment: Does the "Test" button work?

Comment: Yes, but it is important to understand that when testing the Content Type of the request is forced to being *application/json*. This will in turn match my template.

Comment: And you can't remove the required `Content-Type` or replace it with `'*'`?

Comment: It doesn't seem that I can. Perhaps some other wildcard?

Comment: Thanks for this well written question, it helped me solve my issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use content type "application/json".

https://gist.github.com/maruks/e036168263cd412146e6

Comment: Your solution is great and definitely better than what I was able to find in the documentation. However, this means that I need to know beforehand all the content types that I might receive. Is there  way to specify something like a wildcard content type that will capture even requests without a set content type (or different ones all together)?

Comment: @Interfector I believe its not yet possible to have a default/wildcard handler. There is no official response yet from Amazon for [this question](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=665906#665906) on their forum.

Comment: The application/json is the default content-type.

If no content-type has been specified in the request, the mapping template for application/json will be used to create the event for Lambda.

If a content-type has been set in the request, then it seems that you need to have a template for each possible content-type.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the Accept and Content-Type headers in your curl request? Below I'm assuming you are sending "text/plain" and can accept json in the response

```
-H "Content-Type: text/plain" -H "Accept: application/json"
```

Comment: I just tried that and it doesn't work. The accept part is redundant, I would just take in whatever was thrown at me. I also tried setting the Content-Type to application/json hoping I've missed some wizardry from Amazon.